# gnuplot: smooth line in polar coordinates

Tags: gnuplot

I tried to plot some data in polar coordinates with gnuplot and then draw a smooth line.

data.dat:

```
0 10
20 15
40 40
60  80
80  140
100 140
120 80
140 40
160 15
180 10
```

gnuplot:

```
set polar
set angle degrees
set grid
set grid polar
plot "data.dat" smooth csplines
```

I expected gnuplot to draw ovoid curve between points, but it drew strange line from left to right ignoring polar coordinates. Do you think there is any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

csplines are cubic so that's the best you can get with them. Try

```
plot 'data.dat' smooth bezier
```

but even then, you can't achieve much with such a small data set.

There is another trick you can try but it improves things only a little: you first output a table of the data generated by `smooth bezier` normal plot and then plot them polar:

```
# save smooth bezier data
set table
set output 'b_data.dat'
plot 'data.dat' smooth bezier

# plot
unset table
set term x11
set polar
set angle degrees
set grid
set grid polar
plot "b_data.dat" w lines
```

Comment: thank you, bezier looks better, but it makes much smaller curve than my data are

Comment: @paolo: I don't think you can do much about it :/ I updated the answer a little.